# How to make sure the same number is not used twice?

Tags: java

I am making a bingo game in Java. In bingo, there is a ball that has a number and each player has a card and they check to see if they have that number. If they get 5 in a row on their card they get a bingo. Currently, c1 is my variable for the ball number. (there will be more than one card later on but I need to fix this)

```
try
{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
catch(InterruptedException ex)
{
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

int c1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(75);
    
int Bingo = 0;
while(Bingo == 0){
    c1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(75);
    
    if(c1 == b1 || c1 == b2 || c1 == b3 || c1 == b4 || c1 == b5){
        while(c1 != c1){
            b++;
            System.out.println("B " + c1);
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    else if(c1 == i1 || c1 == i2 || c1 == i3 || c1 == i4 || c1 == i5){
        i++;
        System.out.println("I " + c1);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    else if(c1 == n1 || c1 == n2 || c1 == n3 || c1 == n4 || c1 == n5){
        n++;
        System.out.println("N " + c1);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    else if(c1 == g1 || c1 == g2 || c1 == g3 || c1 == g4 || c1 == g5){
        g++;
        System.out.println("G " + c1);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    else if(c1 == o1 || c1 == o2 || c1 == o3 || c1 == o4 || c1 == o5){
        o++;
        System.out.println("O " + c1);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

That generates the numbers with a delay (that is good) but I don't want to use the same number twice it generates a number an unknown amount of times.

Comment: Create a List with the numbers 1 - 75.  Shuffle the List.

Comment: Also, give your variables meaningful names. They don't have to be that short. Do you think you'll remember what each variable represents if you look at your code again in 6 months' time?

Comment: Also, `c1` will be 0 to 74 so you probably want to increment it. You could use an array of booleans to check for duplicates. If associated entry is `true` then ignore the value else set the entry to `true`. You would want to do this before incrementing `c1`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments - you could just store the numbers in a shuffled list and just pop values off.  This gets a little weird because you can only pop 75 values until you need to replenish the list and your range of possible values is stored up front in memory.  An alternative approach is to maintain a Set of seen values

```
Set<Integer> seenValues = new HashSet<>();
```

and add values to the Set as you serve them up and of course check to see if the value you are currently serving is already in the `seenValues`.

Comment: Ok so do I do `Set<Integer> seenValues = new HashSet<>(); while(c1.containsseenValues){(generate new number);}` I hate not being able to use enter... But clearly I would put code in the while loop. I haven't done java very long

Comment: What do you mean not being able to use enter?

Comment: on this site I can't use enter to make a new line

Comment: Afgani You never answered me... "Ok so do I do Set<Integer> seenValues = new HashSet<>(); while(c1.containsseenValues){(generate new number);}" you asked about the part that matters the least...

Comment: That's because your question is incoherent.  Why don't you try something with the Set and tell us if you get stuck.

Comment: Are you really sitting there waiting for me to say "yes, do that" before you try?  I think you should consider another profession.

Comment: I'm not going to be a programmer when I grow up. I'm going to be a teacher.

Comment: yeah I guess that makes you exempt from having to know how things work then.  good luck!